# limitar numeros y comas x jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo un input text , donde quisiera limitar los caracteres ingresados por el usuario a "solo números y comas" , o sea :

Ej1 :  "1001,1002,1003"
Ej2 :  "1001"
Ej3 :  "1001,2002"

Como podría hacerlo en jquery ? copio fragmento del código :

```html
   <div id="marco">
    <span id="nombre_campo">Ingrese el Nº de planilla : </span><input type="text" data-planilla="" id="cajita" name="ingreso" autofocus>
    <input type="button" id="boton1" name="enviar" data-planilla="NO"  onclick="Muestro_Valor()" value="Buscar">
   </div>
```

Comment: Si bien es redundante, aclaro que el input text es "cajita" . slds

Comment: Ahi saque mi respuesta agrega al titulo entre parentesis la version de jquery que tenes asi alguien que venga usandolo hace mucho puede ayudarte, yo lo empece a usar hace poco, sigo buscando

Comment: Juan todo ok, gracias ! Use una version mas nueva de jquery la 1.9 , no me generó otros conflictos y tu rutina me funciono perfecto.

Comment: Bueno ahi puse la respuesta devuelta para que quede entonces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con ese script solo dejas que en el input ponga numero y comas.

```js
 $('.input-number').on('input', function () { 
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g,'');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input-number" value="" />
```

Respondiendo a tu consulta en el comentario te dejo un ejemplo de como se me ocurrio hacerlo es probable que haya 10.000 formas mejores pero solo me salio esa.
Probe haciendolo solo con addClass y removeClass pero no funciona debe ser por la inicializacion del input asi que directamente lo remuevo del dom y lo vuelvo a generar con otra clase. Repito, tomalo como una "guia" de cual puede llegar a ser la idea, recien lo hice, ya lo miro y te digo por seguro que debe haber una forma muchisimo mejor.

```js
 $('#select').on('change', function() {

  if(this.value == 0){
   $("#cajita").remove()
   $("#contenedor").html("<input type='text' data-planilla=' id='cajita' name='ingreso' autofocus class='conRestriccion' placeholder='Aplica restriccion'>")
  }
  else{
   $("#cajita").remove()
   $("#contenedor").html("<input type='text' data-planilla=' id='cajita' name='ingreso' autofocus class='sinRestriccion' placeholder='Aplica sin restriccion'>")
  }

$('.conRestriccion').on('input', function () { 
 this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g,'');
});

});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-TXsBwvYEO87oOjPQ9ifcb7wn3IrrW91dhj6EMEtRLvM="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select name="" id="select">
<option value="vacio">Seleccionar una opcion</option>
<option value="0">Con restriccion</option>
<option value="1">Sin restriccion</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<div id="marco">
<span id="nombre_campo">Ingrese el Nº de planilla : </span>
<div id="contenedor">
 <input type="text" data-planilla="" id="cajita" name="ingreso" autofocus class="sinRestriccion" placeholder="Inicia sin restricción">
</div><br>
<input type="button" id="boton1" name="enviar" data-planilla="NO"  onclick="Muestro_Valor()" value="Buscar">
</div>
```

Comment: Estoy usando :
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

Comment: y he adaptado a mi codigo asi :   
$('#cajita').on('input', function () { 
   this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g,'');
  });

Comment: Por que motivo no funciona y me traba todo ? comento la funcion y vuelve a funcionar ..

Comment: Acabo de ver version por version de Jquery, el codigo que te pase funciona a partir de la 1.7.0 y actualmente va por la 3.3.1, voy a investigar pero no se como se hara en una version tan antigua

Comment: Juan , algo que no se como hacer y se me pasó. Yo aplique al input :   $('#cajita').on('input', function () { this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g,'');});   , pero segun lo que elijo utilizo el mismo input para ingreso sin restricciones, como limpio el replace ?

Comment: Ahi modifique mi respuesta